# Can Tabhost replaced by Images in Android?

Tags: android

How can I set Images that it looks like I've set Tab host?Please help 
I want same look and feel like Tab host without Tabhost...

Comment: yes,we can set background image for tabhost

Comment: No.. I mean we 'll not use Tabhost.. We just set our Images like it looks like tabhost

Comment: it mean  we click first image it should highlight and second image should not highlight

Comment: take two image for one imageview , in drawable create custome button in XML , write a code on click button setVisibility(View.VISIBLE),and set other layout as setVisibility(View.GONE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your question is not clear.**

You can use buttons in linear layout and set background image and setOnClickListener to it and call activities when click on buttons.

And if you want to add image to tabhost you can refer this link:

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/

Comment: I dont want to use Tabhost..!!!! :) without using it I want it's look and feel... have you any Code or Example? @Surabhi

Comment: <TableLayout> <TableRow> <Button>..android:background="".</> <Button> ... </> <TableRow> </TableLayoute>

Comment: Accept my answer if it works for you.

Comment: :) ,,nice... And what about the Tag which we used?

Answer (score 0):

Create a LinearLayout with buttons with your images as their display, and a viewflipper with content for each tab below it... each button will make the corresponding view active. That will look like tabhost but not use it.

Comment: I have tried it.. but it looks weird... I want same look and feel like Tabhost without Tabhost... Is it possible?

Comment: It's software, so sure it's possible. The sources to Android's UIs are public; you should probably refer to the TabHost source to see exactly how their doing it.